# How to get a key from LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, list, key-value, linkedhashmap

How to get a key from LinkedHashMap?

For example I have `LinkedHashMap` which contains key and user names and I need to input name with the help of scanner after that I want to see what key that element has, the element that I input:

```
static LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> names = new LinkedHashMap<>();
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
static int i = 1;
stasic String name;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int b = 0;
    while (b == 0) {
        System.out.println("Input your name: ");
        name = sc.nextLine;
        names.put(i, name);
        i += 1;
        outName();
    }
}

public static void outName() {
    System.out.println("Input name: ");
    name = sc.nextLine();
    if (names.containsValue(name)) {
        //I do not know what should I do here?
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you are using the map backwards in that case, perhaps you want Map<String, Integer>? then you would just say names.get(name). Also how would you want to handle duplicate names? or are duplicates allowed?

Comment: You seem to be using a `Map` backwards. Oops. This looks a lot like it could be replaced by a `List` - just use `List.indexOf`. Not fast, but it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : names.entrySet()) {
String key = entry.getKey();
ArrayList<String> value = entry.getValue();
}
```

use Map.Entry to iterate

Answer (score 1):

Answer to question "How to get a key from LinkedHashMap?"

```
names.entrySet().stream().findFirst().get().getKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to collect the keys in order they are in Set then it is like this:

```
map.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
```

Here the LinkedHashSet maintains the order of insertion of LinkedHashMap.
If you use HashSet it may change the order of keys. For surety use LinkedHashSet.

Same thing is applicable on case of ArrayList. ArrayList maintains the insertion order, so nothing to worry about order.

```
map.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```